# Transforming UTM layer to WGS using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I am trying transform a UTM layer to a WGS.

I have already:

- Saved it as a new layer changing the SRC
- Tried the tool "define current projection"

I am using QGIS 2.14 and the original layers are in WGS84/UTM 17S EPSG:32717, and my objective is to use WGS84.

Comment: what is the problem? because saving it as a new layer and change the reference system should have worked.

Comment: `Define current projection` is definitely wrong. For `Save As...`, you need to save to a **different** filename, and remove the old layer from the canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using QGIS 2.18. Hope the steps below are helpful:

1. Make sure the shapefile with CRS "WGS84/UTM 17S EPSG:32717".
2. "Save as..". Save it into a new shapefile and change the CRS to WGS84.
3. Uncheck "add into map". Close QGIS and open again, add your new shapefile.

Comment: Thanks Cy T!! I was loading the new layers on the same  map... I never thought that would be an issue