# How can I convert a MULTILINESTRING geodatabase file into a coordinate system with lat / long for individual points in a CSV file?

Tags: qgis, convert, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, esri-geodatabase

I have tried ogr2ogr, and QGIS but nothing seems to work for converting a MULTILINESTRING into individual lat/long coordinates.  I am doing this in order to get it into a flat file so I can rearrange the data for conversion into a data format that requires specific columns for latitude and longitude.  Ideally it would be in CSV format.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24442/converting-polygon-into-single-or-all-points-using-qgis might be what you're after.. are the polylines already in geographic coordinates? If not https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229095/transforming-utm-layer-to-wgs-using-qgis could shed some illumination.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson, I tried these options but it seems that it gets "garbled" in QGIS 3.x, and instead of proper x, y lat/long values int he coordinate plain I end up with x,y columns that give me linear counting values 1,1,2,2,3,3,etc fields which are definitely wrong